# Always hide div if user clicks on a close button

Tags: html, css, hide

On my WordPress site, I have a notification bar at the top that is displayed to **unregistered** users. When user clicks a close button, the notification div is simply hidden with `display: none;`.

The problem is that whenever the user refreshes the page or goes to a different page, it reappears.

My question is, what is the best way to keep this bar always hidden once user clicks the close button? What is good practice in this scenario?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One possible solution is to use [**local storage**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage):

**html**

```
<div>test</div>
<input type="button" value="hide" />
```

**js**

```
$(":button").on("click", function(){    
    $("div").toggle();
    localStorage.setItem("hide", $("div").is(":visible"));
});

localStorage.hide == "false" ? $("div").hide() : $("div").show();
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/q72kys6r/)

Comment: This is interesting. How exactly does local storage work? Where is the information stored? For how long? How compatible is it with browsers and mobile browsers?

Comment: if you click on link is a complete guide :)

Comment: And another interesting article [DOM Storage](http://ejohn.org/blog/dom-storage/)

Comment: Sorry, reading as we speak. I have tested this in Firefox, works fine. But on Safari (and I'm guessing on Chrome too), it doesn't work if you open a new tab/window. Loading the page shows that it isn't stored. Try it to confirm.

Comment: Nope in chrome works great. Check [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: [This plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/storageapi/) will ensure cross-browser local storage (uses cookies if not supported).